# Neo4j Query Not Returning Desired Output

Tags: database, neo4j

Hi I am learning Neo4j Database, I had an issue with one of the query as it seems to be not returning a valid output. Here is my complete dataset [image: Dataset]

Query that giving issue is `MATCH (usr:USER)-[:KNOWS]->(lang:SKILL) where lang.name="Python" AND lang.name="FastAPI" return usr`,
Expected Output is `Vibhav` Node. But instead its not returning any value[image]
Please help me to understand this. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting two predicates on the same node, which will not work as a single node cannot have two names. What you need to do is:

```
MATCH (lang2:SKILL)<-[:KNOWS]-(usr:USER)-[:KNOWS]->(lang:SKILL) 
where lang.name="Python" AND lang2.name="FastAPI" 
return usr
```

Answer (score 1):

From the visualization we can see that some urs have more than one lang skill. So, you could use OR logic and count the returns:

> MATCH (usr:USER)-[r:KNOWS]->(lang:SKILL)  where lang.name="Python" OR
> lang2.name="FastAPI"  with urs, count(*) as ct with usr where ct=2
> return usr

This might run faster that Tomaz's suggestion ... you'll have to test it.This assumes you will not have duplicate edges to a skill node.